Retrieve overlapping polygon attributes between two shapefiles using terra in R
I have two polygon shapefiles, shapefile 1 and shapefile 2. I would like to extract, for each polygon in shapefile 1, the attributes 'CASES' and 'RATE' from polygons in shapefile 2 using terra in R. I tried:
test <- terra::intersect(shp_1, shp_2)
test <- terra::intersect(shp_2, shp_1)

In both cases, it creates a shapefile containing polygons from shapefile 2. However, I would like to obtain a shapefile containing polygons from shapefile 1 with attributes from shapefile 2. More specifically, I would like to keep shapefile 1 and simply add the attributes from shapefile 2. I expect the polygons from shapefile 1 to be duplicated because a polygon from shapefile 1 can have attributes 'CASES' and 'RATE' for multiple years.
Update: Here's an example proposed by Spacedman: If feature 1 from shapefile 1 intersects with 10 features from shapefile 2, the result would be a shapefile where each geometry corresponds to feature 1 from shapefile 1 associated with the attribute of each of the 10 features from shapefile 2. So, we would have a shapefile of 10 geometries corresponding to feature 1 of shapefile 1, each with the attributes from shapefile 2.
Here are the two shapefiles:
Here is my code:"
  shp_1 <- terra::vect("C:/Users/Marine/Dropbox/Test_intersect/HR_000a18a_e.shp")
  shp_2 <- terra::vect("C:/Users/Marine/Dropbox/Test_intersect/canada_ld.shp")
  
  ## Change the projection of the shapefile 1
  shp_1 <- terra::project(shp_1, "EPSG:4326")
  
  ## Retrieve the attributes of polygons from the shapefile 2 that overlap with polygons from the shapefile 1
  test <- terra::intersect(shp_1, shp_2)


I think you've misunderstood what terra::intersect does. shp_1 has 111 polygons, shp_2 has 1330, and test has 7084, which are all the overlaps of shp_1 with shp_2.  You're not getting "polygons from shape 2", you're getting the intersecting polygons with attributes from shape 1 and shape 2. Try plotting eg plot(shp_1[1],lwd=5); plot(shp_2,add=TRUE,border="red",lwd=3); plot(test,add=TRUE,border="green") and you can see the different parts. So what do you want? Do you want, for each poly in shape 1, the attributes from any intersecting shapefile 2 poly? Or some function thereof?

@Spacedman thank you for your comment. Exactly, I would like to obtain, for each polygon in shape 1, the attributes from any intersecting polygon in shapefile 2. More specifically, I would like to keep shapefile 1 and simply add the attributes from shapefile 2.

Yes, but each feature from shapefile 1 may intersect several features from shapefile 2, and those features may have different values for the attributes. If shape 1 feature 1 overlaps 10 features of shapefile 2, and feature 2 of shape 1 overlaps 4 features of shapefile 2, what output do you want? Because the terra data structure is a data frame and you cant have one row with 10 columns and another with 4. What you can have is a data frame of shape 1 ID, shape 2 ID, shape 2 attributes, which is basically what you have from intersect if you drop a few columns.

Just looking at shp_1 again it looks like you've got 15 copies of each geometry (one each for various years), which makes geometry ops like intersect 15 times slower than they need to be. If possible keep geometry separate from repeated data like this and use a unique identifier to link spatial to repeated data at the last stage.

@Spacedman thank you for your comment. If feature 1 from shapefile 1 intersects with 10 features from shapefile 2, the result would be a shapefile (because I've seen that the result of intersect gives a spatVector) where each geometry corresponds to feature 1 from shapefile 1 associated with the attribute of each of the 10 features from shapefile 2. So we would have a shapefile of 10 geometries corresponding to feature 1 of shapefile 1, each with the attributes from shapefile 2.

Is there a reason you are using terra for this and not sf?

No, there's no reason. There's no problem with using sf.

Here's a solution using terra as requested in the title:
library(terra)

# data is in my working folder:
t1 = vect("HR_000a18a_e.shp")
t2 = vect("canada_ld.shp")

# reproject to match - note I get the crs from t2 to guarantee this
t1 = terra::project(t1, crs(t2))

# generate all pairs of intersects
int12 = relate(t1, t2, "intersects", pairs=TRUE)

# combine rows from t1 with rows from t2
t12 = cbind(t1[int12[,1],], t2[int12[,2],,drop=TRUE])

If you look at int12 its like this:
     id.x id.y
[1,]    1  398
[2,]    1  396
[3,]    1  395
[4,]    1  394
[5,]    1  393
...

showing that t1[1] intersects with t2[398], t2[396],.... The last line of my code extracts the matching rows from that 2-column matrix and uses cbind to put them together. It keeps all the attributes from both, and uses drop to leave the geometry of t2 behind and only take the t1 geometry (although I think it drops second geometries anyway so this might not be needed)
Let's just plot something to check if we're okay:
> head(int12[int12[,1]==23,])
     id.x id.y
[1,]   23 1012
[2,]   23 1009

tells us feature 23 of t1 intersects features 1012 and 1009 of t2:
plot(t1[23])
plot(t2[1012], add=TRUE, border="red")


Yes, feature 1012 of t2 intersects the southern part of feature 23 from t1.
Note that "intersects" may include features that intersect only along an edge, if you want actual overlaps, use "overlaps"
I did also try and do this with the sf package but there are some invalid geometry problems that need solving first, and you also need to decide if you want to work in spherical or planar geometry.

Great ! Thank you very much for your help, it's perfect !
